# Spring Boot external properties file (with profiles)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

What I am trying to accomplish, is to specify a directory on my application.yml file located directly on the classpath (under /resources). I would like to be able to have something like:

```
 spring:     
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  profiles:
    active: dev
  config:
    location: C:\\app\\configs\\
```

Then under the c:\settings\configs\ location, I would like to have multiple config files based on the profile being loaded, such as:

```
c:\app\configs:
application-dev.yml
application-staging.yml
application-production.yml
```

Using this approach, the IDE would always default to application-dev.yml. When I build the app via gradle, and run it while passing in the command line arguments, I can specify the profile, thus loading the appropriate file. Ideally, being able to do just this:

> java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging appliation.jar

All the examples or answers I've seen have shown how to pass this all these config options from the command line only, not using

> spring.config.location

and

> spring.profiles.active

from within a default config file (eg: application.yml). Preference is to set this up as described above for minimal deployment.

Thank you for any suggestions / help!

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a try and provide your base configuration as "bootstrap.yml" instead of "application.yml". Afterwards, spring boot should choose the right config depending on the chosen profile from your configuration path.

To me, this seems to be the closest solution to your use case, if you do not want to make use of command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I am going to end up doing, is create a flag on the profiles where are the settings are kept to turn this on/off per tenant. It's a good way to do it, I would just have preferred to keep it contained within Thymeleaf based on an empty value.